# Teiid 12.2.1 ClassCastException when I try to create vdb

Tags: teiid

I am trying out my first sample application with Teiid Designer and i am using Wildfly AS v15.0.1 and Teiid v12.2.1. I created Datasource, VirtualBaseLayer model and FederatedViews successfully, I then proceeded to create a .vdb file and this is what i got.

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.flushCache(FillLayout.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Composite.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.requestLayout(Control.java:2409)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.relayout(ToolBarManager.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:384)
    at org.teiid.designer.ui.common.table.TableAndToolBar.add(TableAndToolBar.java:116)
    at org.teiid.designer.vdb.ui.editor.VdbEditor.createModelsSection(VdbEditor.java:2279)
    at org.teiid.designer.vdb.ui.editor.VdbEditor.createMainPanel(VdbEditor.java:1868)
    at org.teiid.designer.vdb.ui.editor.VdbEditor.createPartControl(VdbEditor.java:1623)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:361)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:998)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:963)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4622)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3205)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$9(WorkbenchPage.java:3110)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3108)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3078)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3061)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:607)
    at org.teiid.designer.vdb.ui.wizards.NewVdbWizard$2.run(NewVdbWizard.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:469)
    at org.teiid.designer.vdb.ui.wizards.NewVdbWizard.finish(NewVdbWizard.java:274)
    at org.teiid.designer.ui.common.wizard.AbstractWizard.performFinish(AbstractWizard.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4173)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3986)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3585)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4173)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3986)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3585)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1441)
```

Has someone encountered similar exception while creating vdb file?

Thank you,
Purnima Das

Comment: Unfortunately, we have not been keeping the Eclipse plugin for Teiid up to date anymore. You can find compatible JBoss Developer Studio on the Teiid website, other than that we are mostly focused on DDL based support.

Comment: Hello Ramesh,

I reverted to earlier version of Teiid and Developer Studio and it worked for me.

Thank you for your response!

Regards, Purnima Das